# Multiple table access in a custom module

Tags: database, magento, entity-attribute-value

I am new to Magento. I need two table in my custom module and I have to load two table as separate collection, ie `Mage::getModel('mymodule/model1')->getcollection()` and `Mage::getModel('mymodule/model2')->getcollection()`

I've followed the link posted here [Magento - possible to have multiple tables for a single model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349058/magento-possible-to-have-multiple-tables-for-a-single-model) but I am stuck. I created two model classes "model1" and "model2", and created same under the "mysql4", my first model works fine, but if I accessed second one it's not working.

How could I use multiple table in a single module?
Thanks in advance.

---

Here is my config.xml

```
<models>
    <module>
        <class>Package_Module_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>module_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </module>
    <module_type1>
        <class>Package_Module_Model_Type1</class>
        <resourceModel>module_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </module_type1>
    <module_mysql4>
        <class>Package_Module_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>
            <module>
                <table>table1</table>
            </module>
            <module_type1>
                <table>table2</table>
            </module_type1>
        </entities>
    </module_mysql4>
```

Comment: Yes, sure. What do you use in the _init method of your models?

Comment: I think you have a problem in a resource model or its calling

Comment: As like  $this->_init('mymodule/model2');

Comment: I created resource model for the second also under the folder mysql4

Comment: What about init method in the resource models?

Comment: $this->_init('mymodule/model2', 'table2_id');

Comment: Could you show code of all your 6 classes: models, resources and setups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one module so only need one module declaration:

```
<models>
    <module>
        <class>Package_Module_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>module_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </module>
    <module_mysql4>
        <class>Package_Module_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>
            <model1>
                <table>table1</table>
            </model1>
            <model2>
                <table>table2</table>
            </model2>
        </entities>
    </module_mysql4>
</models>
```

Here there are several **models** in a single **module's** `entities` list.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this one:

```
<models> 
    <module> 
        <class>Package_Module_Model</class> 
        <resourceModel>module_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </module>
    <module_type1> 
        <class>Package_Module_Model_Type1</class> 
        <resourceModel>module_mysql4_type1</resourceModel> 
    </module_type1> 
    <module_mysql4> 
        <class>Package_Module_Model_Mysql4</class> 
        <entities> 
            <module> 
                <table>table1</table> 
            </module> 
        </entities> 
    </module_mysql4> 
    <module_mysql4_type1> 
        <class>Package_Module_Model_Mysql4_Type1</class> 
        <entities> 
            <module_type1> 
                <table>table2</table> 
            </module_type1> 
        </entities> 
    </module_mysql4_type1> 
</models>
```